# Why is there no such substance as p-phthalic anhydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

Its formula is C6H4(CO)2O.  It is an organic molecule that doesn’t have any branching or functional groups on carbon 4 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

First lets take a look at o-phthalic acid,

[image: o-phthalic acid]

and it's anhydride;

[image: o-phthalic anhydride]

Now as you can see the ring formed in case of o-phthalic anhydride is sterically feasible. The angle strain is not very high and the aromaticity is still intact. Now, take a look at p-phthalic acid;

[image: p-phthalic acid]

Now, if you try to dehydrate this molecule as you see there is a very big steric problem. To accomplish this dehydration, the molecule must take a boat form, which would look something like this,

[image: Boat conformer of cyclo-hexane]
(I am using image of cyclo-hexane just to show you the structure, benzene ring will never do this)

But to accomplish this conformation the benzene ring has to loose it's aromaticity and also create a very unstable system with the pi bond densities repelling each other. So, as this conformation is not Thermodynamically feasible, anhydride formation doesn't take place.

Comment: Would p-phthalic acid dehydrate to form a polymeric anhydride (possibly a goo) or decompose? it does form polymers with dialcohols.

Comment: @James Gaidis I would assume yes as it gives very similar reactions in the production of PET(polyethylene terpthalate) and PBT(polybutylene terpthalate).